# Header content type: image/jpeg not working

Tags: php, forms, image, header

I am new to php and trying to display the image uploaded to form, the code is working as long as I don't specify the header content type. But I want to specify the content type to image/jpeg, the image which was otherwise being displayed is not displayed anymore when content type is applied.It just shows a small box on the top of page with a blue question mark inside and a blue background.
This code is working:

```
if ($filetype == "text/plain"){
    header('Content-type:text/plain');
    echo file_get_contents("./images/$filename");
    } 
else if ($filetype == "image/jpeg"){
    //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo "<img src='images/$filename'>";
    }
```

but its not working with header('Content-type: image/jpeg')

I tried it with echo get_file_contents function as well, but it results in binary code for image without header type, and the same blue question mark thing with header type.

Comment: You're trying to make a binary image out of a bit of HTML, that cannot work. You could try [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
> echo "<img src='images/$filename'>";
> ```

`echo "<img src='images/$filename'>";` is going to output a string of **HTML**. That isn't a JPEG. It has a URL to a JPEG inside it.

The correct content type is `text/html`.